# Want to upload youtube video link on facebook users wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, video

Hi i am working on an application in which i need to upload a you-tube uploaded video on Facebook using URL or we can say i want to post an URL on Facebook.I have integrated Facebook into my application and i can upload photos on Facebook wall but not able to upload video by URL.

Please help me if any one knows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it sound like you have the Graph API up and running?

In that case simply post your URL as a massage like this:

```
-(void)postMessageOnUsersWall:(NSString*)msg
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   msg, @"message", // The status message
                                   nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate: self];
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but i have tried this and still it is not uploading URL on facebook users wall. I have changed msg to URL as a string type but it is not uploading

Comment: Hi sabyasachi, If you could provide some code it would be easier to see what the problem is.